# Replacing Pop-Up window with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to replace a pop up window with a modal in a web application. The previous implementation uses JQuery `$j('input field name', opener.document);` to access values stored on the previous, parent screen - this doesn't work with a modal implementation, it throws an

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative for opener.document for use with Bootstrap Modal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `opener`? Can you profide the code please?

Comment: Just use plain jQuery selectors. Bootstrap modal is just a bunch of divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is to short to give an good answer.

but i can give you an [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmnq0nd0/) with a modal taking text from outside it.

Now i dont know what you mean by previous, parent screen.

But what i think your after is: 
Finding something on that's outside the modal and place it inside.

**Jquery:**

```
var text = $('some-where-you-want-info-from').html();
$('modal-body').prepend(text);`
```

This gets some html from an element and sets it to the modal body

Comment: Hi Persijn, you answer is enough for me to investigate further -  the text I need to get into the modal in an input field included in a JavaScript file on a previous screen to the JavaScript file that deals with the modal... so Screen 1 -> click next -> open modal -> modal scripts from second JS file. In the modal the text is again to be stored to a hidden field. The second JS file is the one that is giving me problems, if I try and access it with jQuery selectors, I continue to get null values...

Comment: Ohhh from a javascript file, well that shouldn't be to hard. Since it was possible before (in the window) that means the variable is still accessible. Then you can just call it directly. So: ` `window.yourvaraible` almost all variables are global in javascript :)

Comment: Happy to help! Rep comes and goes its okay :P

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is with the following syntax:

```js
var myVar = window.parent.document.getElementById('element_name');
```

which seems to copy the value over exactly!

Big thanks to Persijn for pointing me in the right direction with this one!